# FLOW approval email SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook

I'm using Flow to send approval email to the users when item adding to the list.
But I want to send approval email to few users and users how send request can write users emails who will approve it.
How can I realize it?

Answer (score 0):

I think Microsoft Flow is not the correct solution to do this. We faced the same issue with working with Flow for different users to replace the SP-Workflow with it.

BUT the huge difference between standard workflows and Flow is that Flow is not yet build to be used as a collaborative platform...

You cant connect with other users Flows because every Flow binds the specific user account to the different services.

I hope i did not misunderstood your question :)

Comment: Ok, maybe you have some examples with workflows?
Because I'm new in SharePoint and never work before with workflows.